# covert a php array to json object , then back to array in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am trying to get some rows from database as bellow

```
$result = $conn->query($sql); 
$rows = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

`$rows` is a set of associative array , and converting it to json object as bellow

```
$json_string =  json_encode($rows);
```

I wish to print all rows value in JAVASCRIPT. is it possible ?

Comment: use `JSON.parse()`

Comment: So did you tried any thing or just asked because its easy to ask ??

Comment: @SandeepNayak i used but it returns an object , now it is diffulct for how to convert an object into javascript associative array and iterate through it

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI do you know the answer or you answered like this because it is easiest one